# Simplifying code with nested JOINs in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I'm writing an SQL statement in PostgreSQL where I'm JOINing data from different tables that are each connected by foreign keys on their ids. Table b has a field a_id which relates to the id of table a and so on.

My problem is that I want to reuse a value from the joined table in a WHERE clause without having to do all the JOINs again, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON b.a_id = a.id
INNER JOIN c ON c.b_id = b.id
WHERE a.id = 3
AND a.x =
    (SELECT c.y
    FROM a
    INNER JOIN b ON b.a_id = a.id
    INNER JOIN c ON c.b_id = b.id
    WHERE a.id = 3
    AND c.id = 5)
```

I bet there's a simpler solution for this snippet that I'm just not realising. I'll be glad if anybody can help me out.

Comment: Can you describe more  by example?

Comment: Lazy solution: a cte.

Comment: PostgreSQL also supports [LATERAL Subqueries/JOINs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html) , which also might be usefull in this case.. But hard to say for sure without example data and expected result.. See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a silver bullet answer which simplifies your query, but CTEs certainly could make it a bit easier on the eyes:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM a
    INNER JOIN b ON b.a_id = a.id
    INNER JOIN c ON c.b_id = b.id
    WHERE a.id = 3
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE x IN (SELECT y FROM cte WHERE c_id = 5);
```

My aliases or column names may be off, and you may need to tidy up the CTE a bit before it would actually work for you.

Comment: I'd do `IN` instead of `=` sub-query, just in case.

Comment: @jarlh Yeah, I saw that too, but trusted that the OP was certain it could not happen.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the kind of structure I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions for this:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM (SELECT a.*, b.*, c.*,  -- should  list the columns explicitly
             MAX(c.y) FILTER (WHERE c.id = 5) OVER () as y_5
      FROM a INNER JOIN
           b
           ON b.a_id = a.id INNER JOIN
           c
           ON c.b_id = b.id
      WHERE a.id = 3
    ) abc
WHERE abc.x = abc.y_5;
```

Answer (score 0):

**I hope the below-mentioned query will help you.**

```
SELECT *
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON b.a_id = a.id
INNER JOIN c ON c.b_id = b.id
WHERE a.id = 3 and c.id =5 and a.x = c.y
```

Comment: My gut feeling is that your query isn't identical to the logic being used by the OP.  Consider that a record for which `c.id <> 5` could still end up in the result set, if it happens to match `c.y`.

Comment: Prove it. Because in where clause I used 'and' condition not 'or'.

Comment: `Prove it` ... actually it is up to _you_ to prove that the query works using sample data, which granted the OP has provided none.  You will find out soon enough if you're right, as the OP will test your code.

Comment: yeah sure because I am not agreed with your point as 'Consider that a record for which c.id <> 5 could still end up in the result set if it happens to match c.y' because I applied condition with 'and' so if  c.id <> 5 then c.y will not in result set.